# Django Rest Framework : Correct way to override perform_create in ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

*I've now resolved this so scroll down to the bottom of the question to see the resolution*

In Django Rest Framework when an insert takes place on one model I would like to do updates/inserts on other models.

I'm working with a `ModelViewSet` and I've tried overriding the `perform_create` method but the original insert is just swallowed, no update takes place and no errors are seen.

I've tried doing this

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

but although no error is thrown no update takes place either.

Would appreciate an example of overriding `perform_create` so that the original insert still takes place but there is scope for doing other updates/inserts at the same time.

I'm using DRF 3.5.3 .

---

EDIT: Here is the full ModelViewSet code.

```
class AttemptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    API endpoint that allows Attempt to be CRUDed.
    '''

    queryset = Attempt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttemptSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        serializer.save()

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Temporary diagnostic code which should
        be removed once it's possible to update
        an Attempt
        '''

        import os
        import json

        # 'request_auth': request.auth,
        log_data = {
            'user': request.user.pk,

            'remote_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],

            'request_method': request.method,
            'request_path': request.get_full_path(),
            'request_body': request.data ,
            'request_query_params': request.query_params
        }
        if not os.path.exists('/tmp/spellsplashlog'):
            os.makedirs('/tmp/spellsplashlog')

        with open('/tmp/spellsplashlog/logging.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(log_data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

        viewsets.ModelViewSet.initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

... and here's the serializer ...

```
class AttemptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attempt
        fields = '__all__'
```

... and here's the model ...

```
class Attempt(models.Model):
    learner = models.ForeignKey(Learner, related_name='learnerattempts')
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='wordattempts')
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-when']

    class JSONAPIMeta:
        resource_name = "attempts"

    def __str__(self):
        formatted_when = localtime(self.when).strftime('%d-%b-%Y %X')
        if self.success:
            formatted_success = "YES"
        else:
            formatted_success = "NO"

        return u'%s - %s- Success ?: %s ' % (self.word, formatted_when, formatted_success)
```

---

EDIT (and resolution)

OK so I made some changes to the `perform_create` and it seems that in some quite subtle way DRF just doesn't like embedding `pdb.set_trace`. It doesn't fail nosily but it just doesn't respond. Once I removed that it worked as I would expect.

FWIW in the course of investigation I also changed

```
serializer.save
```

to

```
super().perform_create(serializer)
```

but in fact either of those two worked once the `pdb.set_trace` had been removed.

Comment: Can you show full viewset code? Your `perform_create` shouldn't break default behavior.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - Thanks for your response. I've made an edit to the question to include the Viewset.

Comment: Not sure but maybe problem with your `initial` method. Try `super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)` instead of `viewsets.ModelViewSet.initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner : thanks for your suggestion. I made the change but that didn't help ... however in trying what you suggested I also thought of another change and that did work so thank you the shove in the right direction . I'm going to edit the question to indicate the change I made.

Answer (score 3):

you can update another model after serializer.save method gets the call.

```
def perform_create(serializer):
    serializer.save()
    ### here you can write the other logic of update
    ### you can use the signal, just raise signal on save of that model
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I already have what you have suggested and the update doesn't occur ... unless I've misunderstood what you're suggesting . I'm about to update the question to include the full ModelViewSet code so perhaps that will make it clearer. Thanks again .

Comment: can you write what exactly you are trying to achieve.